# Turn a loop based code into a vectorised one in R?

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I´ve got this dataset and want to perform some calculations based on certain conditions:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

filas <- structure(list(Año = c(rep(2020,4),rep(2021,4),2022), 
                        Mes = c(2:5,3:4,9,11,1), 
                        Id = c(rep(1,7),2,2)), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -9L),
                   class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) %>% 
   mutate(fecha = make_date(Año,Mes,1),
          meses_imp = make_date(2999,1,1))
```

| Año | Mes | Id | fecha | meses_imp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 | 2020-02-01 | 2999-01-01 |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 2020-03-01 | 2999-01-01 |
| 2020 | 4 | 1 | 2020-04-01 | 2999-01-01 |
| 2020 | 5 | 1 | 2020-05-01 | 2999-01-01 |
| 2021 | 3 | 1 | 2021-03-01 | 2999-01-01 |
| 2021 | 4 | 1 | 2021-04-01 | 2999-01-01 |
| 2021 | 9 | 1 | 2021-09-01 | 2999-01-01 |
| 2021 | 11 | 2 | 2021-11-01 | 2999-01-01 |
| 2022 | 1 | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 2999-01-01 |

I need to add rows for each "Id" when there are "holes" between two consecutive ones, and count those added rows later. I´ve achieved this using a "while" loop:

```
i <- 2
while(!is.na(filas[i,]$Id)) {
  if (as.double(difftime(filas[i,]$fecha,filas[i-1,]$fecha)) > 31 &
      filas[i,]$Id == filas[i-1,]$Id) {
    filas <- add_row(filas,
                     Id = filas[i,]$Id,
                     fecha = filas[i-1,]$fecha + months(1),
                     meses_imp = pmin(filas[i-1,]$fecha,
                                      filas[i-1,]$meses_imp),
                     .after = i-1)}
  i=i+1}

filas2 <- filas %>%
  group_by(Id,meses_imp) %>% 
  summarise(cant_meses_imp = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(meses_imp != "2999-01-01")

filas <- left_join(filas,
                   filas2,
                   by=c("Id","meses_imp"))
```

| Año | Mes | Id | fecha | meses_imp | cant_meses_imp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 2 | 1 | 2020-02-01 | 2999-01-01 | NA |
| 2020 | 3 | 1 | 2020-03-01 | 2999-01-01 | NA |
| 2020 | 4 | 1 | 2020-04-01 | 2999-01-01 | NA |
| 2020 | 5 | 1 | 2020-05-01 | 2999-01-01 | NA |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2020-06-01 | 2020-05-01 | 9 |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2020-07-01 | 2020-05-01 | 9 |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2020-08-01 | 2020-05-01 | 9 |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2020-09-01 | 2020-05-01 | 9 |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2020-10-01 | 2020-05-01 | 9 |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2020-11-01 | 2020-05-01 | 9 |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2020-12-01 | 2020-05-01 | 9 |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2020-05-01 | 9 |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2021-02-01 | 2020-05-01 | 9 |
| 2021 | 3 | 1 | 2021-03-01 | 2999-01-01 | NA |
| 2021 | 4 | 1 | 2021-04-01 | 2999-01-01 | NA |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2021-05-01 | 2021-04-01 | 4 |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2021-06-01 | 2021-04-01 | 4 |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2021-07-01 | 2021-04-01 | 4 |
| NA | NA | 1 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-04-01 | 4 |
| 2021 | 9 | 1 | 2021-09-01 | 2999-01-01 | NA |
| 2021 | 11 | 2 | 2021-11-01 | 2999-01-01 | NA |
| NA | NA | 2 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| 2022 | 1 | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 2999-01-01 | NA |

Since I`d like to apply this to a much larger dataset (~ 300k rows), how could I rewrite it in a vectorised way so it´s more efficient (and elegant maybe)?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use SQL style joins to create the additional rows and avoid the complex logic and looping

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the following code using `padr` and `zoo` packages.

This idea is to:

1. Add missing dates with the `padr::pad()` function.
2. Remove unwanted lines (non-integer Id values)
3. Create `na` and `grp` columns to identify rows added in `1.`
4. Group by `grp` and create a column `cant_meses_imp` to count the number of consecutive na in each group
5. Select only desired columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(padr)
library(zoo)

filas %>% 
  pad(by = "fecha") %>% # add missing dates
  mutate(Id = na.approx(Id)) %>% # interpolate NA values in Id column
  subset(Id%%1 == 0) %>% # Keep only Id interger

# This part is for generating the cant_meses_imp column
  mutate(na = ifelse(is.na(Mes), 1, 0),
         grp = rle(na)$lengths %>% {rep(seq(length(.)), .)}) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(cant_meses_imp = ifelse(na == 0, NA, n())) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(na, grp))
```

The code does not reproduce exactly the `fecha` column as there is no guidelines for its values.